# Get textbox value in new window using Jquery

Tags: jquery

I have an array of textboxes each having button on right side which when pressed the text should be displayed on new window using Jquery. For demo, you might have seen jquery lightbox plugin which shows the images in the new window. I want exactly same but instead of images i want to show the text value of the text box when its button is pressed.

Please tell me how can i do that?

Comment: are you talking about a window or a dialog?

Answer (score 0):

You can do it like this:

```
var win = window.open();
var doc = win.document;
doc.write($('#textbox_id').val());
doc.close();
```

Answer (score 0):

testopen.html:

```
<html>
      <head></head>
      <body>
         <div id="field1"></div>
         <div id="field2"></div>
      </body>
</html>
```

testopener.html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.3/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
</head>
<body>

    <input id="field1" />
    <input id="field2" />

    <button id="opentest">test</button>
</form>

</body>

<script type="text/javascript">

$(function(){

    var winopen = null;

    $("#opentest").bind("click", function(){

           if (winopen == null || winopen.closed){
            winopen = window.open("testopen.html","", "left=100,top=100,width=250,height=150");
        }

        var field1 = $("#field1").val(),
            field2 = $("#field2").val(),
            ntry = 3,
            sendMsg = function(){

                if (winopen.document.readyState != "complete"){

                    if (ntry >= 0)
                        setTimeout(sendMsg, 1000);

                    ntry--;
                    return;

                }

                $(winopen.document.body).find("#field1").html(field1);
                $(winopen.document.body).find("#field2").html(field2);

          }

        sendMsg();

    });

});

</script>
```

links

http://jquery.com/demo/thickbox/

http://www.no-margin-for-errors.com/projects/prettyphoto-jquery-lightbox-clone/

http://www.ericmmartin.com/projects/simplemodal/

Comment: You have written a very good code but may be i was looking for dialog box or windows but it allow me to make changes and then send back changes to original textbox from where it was taken. Secondly, i'm looking for same effect as jquery lightbox plugin. Is it possible?

Thank you so much for your code and time

Answer (score 0):

If you would like to show ony texts, I strongly suggest to use dialog instead of the plugin.

There are lots of plugin out there to achieve this,which supports to show both images and texts.

http://fancybox.net/

http://colorpowered.com/colorbox/

http://dev.iceburg.net/jquery/jqModal/#

http://jqueryui.com/demos/dialog/

Comment: Yes you are right infact i'm looking for dialog box, i have gone through the links and i think fancybox is what i need.
Thanks alot.

Comment: Kai, tell me if it is possible to run a small ajax script in "inline HTML. For example i get the textvalue using "inline HTML" and then modify the text using Ajax in same inline HTML (popup window). Is this all possible?

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this:

```
$('input#mybutton').click(function() {
    var text = $('textarea#mytextarea').val();
});
```

So, when the button is clicked, the content from textarea will be collected to a variable. After, you just need to inject that variables content on your destination:

1. alert()
2. plugin for popup window
3. custom popup window
4. open a new browser window with that content
   etc...